# Can you define name for a UDF then specify parameters outside the definition?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

Is it possible to use a `Defined Name` for a `User Defined Function`, then declare its parameters outside of the definition?

If I want `MyFunction(ByVal val As String, ByVal position As Integer, Optional ByVal separator As String = ",")` to be defined:

- Go to Formulas -> Define Name
- Name: MyNamedFunction
- Scope: Workbook
- Refers to: MyFunction
- Press OK

When I define the name, I don't get an error.

But when I reference the function in a cell with `=MyNamedFunction(B2, 0)`, it gives me `#REF!`.

Comment: When you enter your UDF into the cell does autocomplete pickup the function? (Also what version of Excel are you using?)

Comment: @NickSlash Yup, both the Named and the actual Function